# NiFi ExecuteScript (Groovy): Using Pdfbox to extract text/images from PDF: error loading modules

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, pdfbox

**NiFi 1.11.4**

Hi there,

I found an interesting solution for extracting text and images from pdf files with ExecuteScript (Groovy):

- [Cloudera article](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-NiFi-and-Pdfbox-to-extract-images-from-PDF/ta-p/246968)
- [fun nifi article](http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/executescript-extract-text-metadata.html)

([NiFi template on github](https://gist.github.com/mattyb149/48e72a26d0f62f330e30))

The Groovy Script starts with

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def s = new PDFTextStripper()
```

With **PDFBox 1.8.16** the script run without errors, but the PDFTextStripper is always empty (and yes: the pdf files contains text, not images)

With **PDFBox 2.0.19** the script didn't run:

**Module Directory** for pdfbox 2.0

```
29.04.2020  12:56         2.715.618 pdfbox-2.0.19.jar
29.04.2020  19:36           257.911 pdfbox-debugger-2.0.19.jar
29.04.2020  19:36            81.206 pdfbox-tools-2.0.19.jar
29.04.2020  19:36           247.912 preflight-2.0.19.jar
29.04.2020  19:36           132.182 xmpbox-2.0.19.jar
29.04.2020  19:36         1.561.265 fontbox-2.0.19.jar
```

**error**

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: 
startup failed:
Script9.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class PDFTextStripper 
@ line 18, column 9.def 
  s = new PDFTextStripper()
```

Any idea, what is missing?

Thanx
Frank

Comment: *"With PDFBox 1.8.16 the script run without errors, but the PDFTextStripper is always empty"* - you don't appear to apply the `PDFTextStripper` to a pdf. Thus, it being empty seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PDFTextStripper` has been refactored to a new package. In pdfbox 1.8.x it indeed was in `org.apache.pdfbox.util` but since 2.0.0 it is in `org.apache.pdfbox.text`.

Thus, you need to adjust your `import` statements for use with pdfbox 2.x.